# $_{m}A=0\Leftrightarrow \text{Ext}{{\left( A,\mathbb{Z} \right)}_{m}}=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

> For any abelian group $A$, let $mA=\left\{ b\in A\mid b=ma,a\in A \right\}$, $_{m}A=\left\{ a\in A\mid ma=0 \right\}$, ${{A}_{m}}=A/mA$. Prove: $_{m}A=0\Leftrightarrow \text{Ext}{{\left( A,\mathbb{Z} \right)}_{m}}=0$.

I know the $0{{\to }_{m}}A\to A\to mA\to 0$ is an exact sequence and $Hom\left( _{m}A,\mathbb{Z} \right)=0$. So $0\to Ext\left( mA,\mathbb{Z} \right)\to Ext\left( A,\mathbb{Z} \right)\to Ext\left( _{m}A,\mathbb{Z} \right)\to 0$ is an exact sequence.

Comment: The body of your question should contain, well, a *question*, as well as your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Can you prove the same statement with the Ext-group replaced by $\operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb Q/Z)$? You can reduce to this statement.

Comment: @MooS Do you mean $Ext{{\left( A,Z \right)}_{m}}=0\Leftrightarrow Hom{{\left( A,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \right)}_{m}}=0$?

Comment: Yes. Use the snake lemma to see this. To finally prove the statement, use tensor-hom-adjunction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof in a two steps:

**1)**

Let $m \in \mathbb Z$ also denote the multiplication $\mathbb Z \xrightarrow{\cdot m} \mathbb Z$.

$0=A_m=A/mA$ is equivalent to the surjectivity of $A \xrightarrow{\cdot m} A$ or in other words: The functor $\operatorname{Hom}(-,A)$ takes $m$ to a surjective map.

$0={}_mA=\{a \in A|ma=0 \}$ is equivalent to the injectivity of $A \xrightarrow{\cdot m} A$ or in other words: The function $- \otimes A$ takes $m$ to an injective function. Note that the dual functor $\operatorname{Hom}(-,\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)$ is not only exact, but it also reflects injections, i.e. the above is equivalent to the statement that the functor $\operatorname{Hom}(- \otimes A,\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)$ takes $m$ to a surjective map.

Thus we have shown:

$0={}_mA$ is equivalent to the fact that the functor $\operatorname{Hom}(- \otimes A,\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)$ takes $m$ to a surjective map.

$\operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)_m=0$ is equivalent to the fact that the functor $\operatorname{Hom}(-,\operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z))$ takes $m$ to a surjective map.

By tensor-hom adjunction these are the same functors, i.e. we have shown

$$0={}_mA \Longleftrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)_m=0.$$

**2)**

Now consider the commutative diagram of exact sequences

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> \mathbb Z @>>> \mathbb Q @>>> \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z @>>> 0 \\
{} @VV{\cdot m}V @VV{\cdot m}V @VV{\cdot m}V \\
0 @>>> \mathbb Z @>>> \mathbb Q @>>> \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z @>>> 0
\end{CD}$$

Apply $\operatorname{Hom(A,-)}$ to get a commutative diagram of long exact sequences:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> \operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb Z) @>>> \operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb Q) @>>> \operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z) @>>> \operatorname{Ext}^1(A,Z) @>>> 0 \\
{} @VV{\cdot m}V @VV{\cdot m}V @VV{\cdot m}V @VV{\cdot m}V \\
0 @>>> \operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb Z) @>>> \operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb Q) @>>> \operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z) @>>> \operatorname{Ext}^1(A,Z) @>>> 0 
\end{CD}$$

Of course we can make this into short exact sequences:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> \operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb Q)/\operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb Z) @>>> \operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z) @>>> \operatorname{Ext}^1(A,Z) @>>> 0 \\
{} @VV{\cdot m}V @VV{\cdot m}V @VV{\cdot m}V \\
0 @>>> \operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb Q)/\operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb Z) @>>> \operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z) @>>> \operatorname{Ext}^1(A,Z) @>>> 0 
\end{CD}$$

Now it is easy to see that $\operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb Q)$ is divisible for any $A$, hence $\operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb Q)/\operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb Z)$ is also divisible as a quotient. Thus the left vertical map is surjective, i.e. by the snake lemma the middle vertical map is surjective if and only if the right vertical map is. Thus we have shown:

$$\operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)_m=0 \Longleftrightarrow \operatorname{Ext}^1(A,Z)_m=0.$$

This completes the proof.